# Find the intersection of the the sets given

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $aN= \{ ax:x\in N \}$ then $3N\cap 7N$ =

Options are 
a)3N
b)7N
c)N
d)21N

I think the answer should be 3N as 7N would contain 3N and we have to find their intersection. But the answer is 21N, and I am not able to figure out the reason for that answer.

Comment: You mean intersection not union. At least that's what $A \cap B$ means.

Comment: numbers that are multiples of $3$ and of $7$ are multiples of $21$

Comment: @coffeemath you are right. Fixed it

Comment: @J.W.Tanner but aren’t we supposed to find the intersection? So it should only include the common elements.

Comment: Why do you think $7\mathbb N$ should contain $3\mathbb N$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner To be more precise: A number is both a multiple of $3$ and a multiple of $7$ if **and only if** it is a multiple of $21$.

Comment: If $t \in 3\Bbb{N} \cap 7\Bbb{N}$, then there exists $a,b \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $$t=3a=7b.$$ This means $3 \mid 7b$, so (can you see why) $3 \mid b$?....In general, along the same lines we can show that $x\Bbb{N} \cap y\Bbb{N}=\text{lcm}(x,y)\Bbb{N}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$7\mathbb{N}$ does not contain $3 \mathbb{N}$ since there is no $x \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $3=7x$, so $3 \notin 7\mathbb{N}$

You should think of $k\mathbb{N}$ as the set of natural multiples of $k$

So, since being in the intersection means being in both sets, how do we call a number who is multiple of $3$ and $7$? We call it a multiple of $21$, don't we?

Answer (score 0):

Think about it this way:

$3N=\{n:n\in N\land 3\mid n\}$

$7N=\{n:n\in N\land 7\mid n\}$

For an two sets $A$ and $B$, such that $A=\{a:\varphi(a)\}$ and $B=\{b:\psi(b)\}$, the intersection is $A\cap B= \{c:\varphi(c)\land\psi(c)\}$

So...

$$3N\cap7N=\{n:n\in N\land (3\mid n)\land (7\mid n)\}$$

If $3$ divides $n$ and $7$ divides $n$, then $n$ must be a multiple of $21$ (since $3$ and $7$ are prime and $21$ is their least common multiple).

Hence, $3N\cap7N=21N$.